# How does the size of a spectrogram relate to window length and frame rate?

Tags: audio, dft, spectrogram, stft

I'm trying to understand the methodology from section 4 in [this report](http://www.cs.tut.fi/sgn/arg/dcase2016/documents/challenge_technical_reports/Task1/Eghbal-Zadeh_2016_task1.pdf) about audio classification but I have some trouble understanding how they pre-process the data (dsp is not my area).

- $30$ seconds audio clips are available, sampled at $22050\textrm{ samples/s}$.
- The STFT is computed *"on $2048$ sample windows at a frame rate of $31.25\textrm{ frames/s}$"*

Somehow this results in spectrograms of size $149\times 149$ which are then feeded to a neural network.

- Does each spectrogram cover $2048$ samples of the audio clip?
- If so, is then $149$ the number of segments that we divide each spectrogram in?
- So that $2048/149 = 13.745$ is the number of samples that we use for computing the DFT in each segment? How can this be a non-integer?

  To my understanding the frame rate is about how much overlap there are between windows, in this case the overlap would be $22050/31.25 = 705.6 \textrm{ samples}$, is that correct? How can this be a non-integer?

Comment: "a report": which report? Cite! We can only guess from the numbers you're giving. Also, not all papers fully describe what they're doing, so this might simply be a case of "sorry, we don't know what the authors did, either".

Comment: Ok, added a link. But i think i gave all the relevant information.